# sending data on the client side with node.js rest api can be done every 5s?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

i want to send data to client side with node.js every 5s. it is a coordinate data i want to send to do realtime location. i use mqtt client , firebase realtime databas to store and retrieve data and flutter to show live location. my problem, is how can i send every 5s data from node.js to client

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');


const port = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')
var firebase = require('firebase');
const server = http.Server(app)

//fetching data from firebase realtime database
function readDatas() {
  let coordinateData = new Array()
  
  loraRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      coordinateData.push(childSnapshot.val().message);
      // console.log('ok');    
   },
   );
  });
```

```
//inserting data  into firebase realtime database
function insert_message(topic, message, packet) {
  loraRef.push({
    message
  })
}
```

```
//inserting data from mqtt into firebase realtime database
function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message, packet) {
    if(message){
      let messageObject = JSON.parse(message)
    insert_message(topic, messageObject, packet)
    }
    

  };
```

```
client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived)
```

```
//sending data to http client
let dataCoordinate = readDatas()
app.get('/coordinate', async(req, res) => {
  console.log('Returning coordinate list');
  
  
  
  if(dataCoordinate.length !==0){
    res.send(dataCoordinate[0]);
    
    //res.sendStatus(dataCoordinate)
    console.log(readDatas()[0]);
  }
  
});
```

Comment: The api you have written for sending data to http client is a REST API means it need to be called from http client, you cannot sent data automatically from this api unless a call for the API is invoked.

For sending the data purpose you have to use the events of mqtt on the client side as well (I don't know much about mqtt so if there is any other chance for Socket.io then you will be able to listen to that event on the client side)